# Paypal sandbox Recurring Payments ipn

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am doing recurring payment.  After the payment is complete and reverted back to the return url, I am not getting the ipn response.  This is my code for recurring payment:

```
    $query = array();
    $query['cmd'] = '_xclick-subscriptions';
    $query['upload'] = '1';

    $query['business'] = $select_paypal_detail[0]->business_mail;

    $product = $_POST['package'];
    //$product_price = $_POST['price'];
    $product_quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

    $query['a3'] = $_POST['price'];
    $query['p3'] = 1;
    $query['t3'] = 'D';
    $query['no_note'] = 1;

    //$query['amount'] = $_POST['price'];

    $query['discount_rate'] = $_POST['discount'];
    $query['item_name'] = $_POST['package'];

    $query['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];

    $query['currency'] =  'CAD';
    $query['instId'] = '211616';
    $query['testMode'] = 100;
    $_SESSION['order_number'] = $order_number;
    $query['cartId'] = 'Order Number '.$_POST['order_number'];
    $query['return'] = $select_paypal_detail[0]->return_url;
    $query['notify_url'] = "http://theelitecoachingacademy.com/?AngellEYE_Paypal_Ipn_For_Wordpress&action=ipn_handler";

    // Prepare query string
    $query_string = http_build_query($query);   

    if( $select_paypal_detail[0]->payment_type == 'live' ){
    ?>

    <!--/header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . $query_string);
    header('Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . $query_string);-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
                 window.location="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?<? echo $query_string ?>";
    </script>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                 window.location="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?<? echo $query_string ?>";
    </script>
    <?php
}?>
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: i am getting only two variables in response [auth] and [form_charset]. I want the transaction id and payment status

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavaScript to redirect in PHP first of all.

```
$paypalHost = $select_paypal_detail[0]->payment_type == 'live' ? 'paypal.com' : 'sandbox.paypal.com';

$query = array();
$query['cmd'] = '_xclick-subscriptions';
$query['upload'] = '1';

$query['business'] = $select_paypal_detail[0]->business_mail;

$product = $_POST['package'];
//$product_price = $_POST['price'];
$product_quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

$query['a3'] = $_POST['price'];
$query['p3'] = 1;
$query['t3'] = 'D';
$query['no_note'] = 1;

//$query['amount'] = $_POST['price'];

$query['discount_rate'] = $_POST['discount'];
$query['item_name'] = $_POST['package'];

$query['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];

$query['currency'] =  'CAD';
$query['instId'] = '211616';
$query['testMode'] = 100;
$_SESSION['order_number'] = $order_number;
$query['cartId'] = 'Order Number '.$_POST['order_number'];
$query['return'] = $select_paypal_detail[0]->return_url;
$query['notify_url'] = "http://theelitecoachingacademy.com/?AngellEYE_Paypal_Ipn_For_Wordpress&action=ipn_handler";

header('Location: https://www.' . $paypalHost . '/cgi-bin/webscr?' . http_build_query($query));
// usually, it's a good idea to exit after redirecting... in this case, it doesn't matter as the redirect is the last thing
exit;
```

In terms of your actual problem, I would check `business` variable is actually pointing to the right account depending on whether you are in sandbox mode or live mode because I would expect them to be different. As the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#html-variables-for-recurring-payments-buttons) mention, the `business` variable is the PayPal ID or an email address associated with your account.

If you are sure that everything is correct, then I would check your IPN handler using the Paypal's IPN simulator.